# Cannot destructure property "subscriptions of "undefined" - vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension that takes in the language of the document and generates a hello world template based on that. I have generated a status bar icon and that is also not showing up. This is my first extension so I am new to all of this. When I run the command with Control + Shift + P it also gets an error that the command is not found.

The code...

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import "typescript";
import "./constants";

let myStatusBar : vscode.StatusBarItem;

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext, { subscriptions }: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const codeBoilerplateCommand = 'code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerplate';
    subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand(codeBoilerplateCommand, () => {
        const documentFileType = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;
        const documentFilePath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName.split('/');

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Generating your Code Boilerplate... ⌛")
        if (documentFileType === "javascript") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!")');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "python") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'print("Hello World!")');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "typescript") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!");');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "csharp") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'using System;');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(3,0), 'namespace' + documentFileName + ' {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(6,4), 'class HelloWorld {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(9, 8), 'static void Main(string[] args) {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(12,12), 'Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(14,8), '}');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(15, 4), '}');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(16, 0), '}');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "c") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), '#include <stdio.h>');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(1,0), 'int main() {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(2,4), 'printf("Hello World!");');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(3,4), 'return 0;');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(4,0), '}');
            })
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "cpp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "java") {
            return null;
        }
    }));

    myStatusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 100);
    myStatusBar.command = codeBoilerplateCommand;
    subscriptions.push(myStatusBar);

    subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(updateStatusBarItem));
    subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(updateStatusBarItem));
    updateStatusBarItem();
}

function updateStatusBarItem(): void {
    myStatusBar.text = `$(new-file) Hello World!`;
    myStatusBar.show();
}

export function deactivate() {
    myStatusBar.dispose();
}
```

Comment: seems like undefined object is being passed in as the second parameter for activate function. check what's being passed in.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Where did you see that `activate` takes a second parameter after the `context`?

Comment: The context: vscode.ExtensionContext was causing an error - removed and everything was working smoothly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably want to leave it as `export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)` and refer to `context.subscriptions` in the body of the function - in case you may need access to the other properties of the `ExtensionContext` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your function's prototype is incorrect, `activate` only takes one argument. To access the subscriptions, do:

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(...
}
```